# Scheduling the selenium maven project for executing the test cases

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cron, junit4

I have a maven project which has selenium scripts.
We are using Junit framework.
I want to schedule it using any of the scheduler services.
I want to know how to schedule it.
Can I use Windows Task Scheduler? or can I use Cron job or Jenkins.
Which is good?.
Since its a maven project is it possible to just a windows Task Scheduler.
Please provide me the commands or steps as how to do it in any of the scheduler services.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). Since you are using `JUnit` you can use a plugin to get nice reports like this:

[image: JUnit report]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is a good choice for these cases:

```
- the job should be available for multiple remote users
- job access should be managed
- you would like to keep logs and statistics
```

Cron is good for local Unix/Linux usage

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows task scheduler then you can only run in Windows only..

If you choose Jenkins you can run your scripts in cross platform

In Jenkins,
1. Download Jenkins war file from Jenkins site
2. Run it using java in cmd
3. Navigate to http://localhost:8080 in a browser
4. Configure java home and maven home in Jenkins
5. Create the maven project job
6. Configure your version control like github wherever your code is..
7. Configure email id to receive reports via mail
8. Finally hit build to start running your scripts or you can schedule build at specific time using schedule build plugin